# WebDriverException For Edge Browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, geb, browser-automation, selenium-edgedriver

I am trying to automate a website on Microsoft Edge browser using geb. The test script is running fine on IE and Chrome but giving an error on Edge browser. The error is:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: ÀՉ았Չtor not implemented (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
    Build info: version: '3.8.0', revision: '924c4067df', time: '2017-11-30T11:20:39.408Z'
    System info: host: 'NAG1-LDL-41716', ip: '172.18.8.41', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
    Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, browserName: MicrosoftEdge, browserVersion: 20.10240.17146.0, javascriptEnabled: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 10, takesElementScreenshot: true, takesScreenshot: true}
    Session ID: 5627381E-0A38-4DE4-BF2C-71FC625049F6
    *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=/*}

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:371)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:473)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at geb.navigator.factory.BrowserBackedNavigatorFactory.createBase(BrowserBackedNavigatorFactory.groovy:39)
    at geb.navigator.factory.BrowserBackedNavigatorFactory.getBase(BrowserBackedNavigatorFactory.groovy:45)
    at geb.content.NavigableSupport.getBase(NavigableSupport.groovy:34)
    at geb.content.NavigableSupport.module(NavigableSupport.groovy:207)
    at geb.content.PageContentTemplateFactoryDelegate.module(PageContentTemplateFactoryDelegate.groovy:31)
    at pages.EbayHomePage._clinit__closure2$_closure3(EbayHomePage.groovy:15)
    at pages.EbayHomePage._clinit__closure2$_closure3(EbayHomePage.groovy)
    at geb.content.PageContentTemplate.invokeFactory(PageContentTemplate.groovy:98)
    at geb.content.PageContentTemplate.create_closure1(PageContentTemplate.groovy:59)
    at geb.content.PageContentTemplate.create_closure1(PageContentTemplate.groovy)
    at geb.content.PageContentTemplate.create(PageContentTemplate.groovy:83)
    at geb.content.PageContentTemplate.get(PageContentTemplate.groovy:54)
    at geb.content.DefaultPageContentSupport.getContent(DefaultPageContentSupport.groovy:42)
    at geb.content.PageContentSupport.propertyMissing(PageContentSupport.groovy:39)
    at geb.Page.propertyMissing(Page.groovy:112)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyTryThese(Closure.java:312)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyDelegateFirst(Closure.java:302)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.getProperty(Closure.java:287)
    at tests.SearchTest.Searching iPhone 6_closure2(SearchTest.groovy:20)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
    at tests.SearchTest.Searching iPhone 6(SearchTest.groovy:19)


org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: not implemented (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.8.0', revision: '924c4067df', time: '2017-11-30T11:20:39.408Z'
System info: host: 'NAG1-LDL-41716', ip: '172.18.8.41', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, browserName: MicrosoftEdge, browserVersion: 20.10240.17146.0, javascriptEnabled: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 10, takesElementScreenshot: true, takesScreenshot: true}
Session ID: 5627381E-0A38-4DE4-BF2C-71FC625049F6

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:658)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getPageSource(RemoteWebDriver.java:483)
    at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.getPageSource(PageSourceReporter.groovy:42)
    at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.writePageSource(PageSourceReporter.groovy:38)
    at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.writeReport(PageSourceReporter.groovy:29)
    at geb.report.CompositeReporter.writeReport(CompositeReporter.groovy:31)
    at geb.Browser.report(Browser.groovy:931)
    at geb.spock.GebReportingSpec.report(GebReportingSpec.groovy:59)
    at geb.spock.GebReportingSpec.cleanup(GebReportingSpec.groovy:46)

Starting server... 
Fully qualified URI to listen on: http://localhost:22259/ 
Waiting for new request... 

Received a request for http://localhost:22259/status 
Waiting for new request... 

Received a request for http://localhost:22259/session 
Waiting for new request... 

Received a request for http://localhost:22259/session/5627381E-0A38-4DE4-BF2C-71FC625049F6/url 
Waiting for new request... 

Received a request for http://localhost:22259/session/5627381E-0A38-4DE4-BF2C-71FC625049F6/url 
Waiting for new request... 

Received a request for http://localhost:22259/session/5627381E-0A38-4DE4-BF2C-71FC625049F6/title 
Waiting for new request... 

Received a request for http://localhost:22259/session/5627381E-0A38-4DE4-BF2C-71FC625049F6/title 
Waiting for new request... 

Received a request for http://localhost:22259/session/5627381E-0A38-4DE4-BF2C-71FC625049F6/title 
Waiting for new request... 

Received a request for http://localhost:22259/session/5627381E-0A38-4DE4-BF2C-71FC625049F6/element 
Waiting for new request... 

Received a request for http://localhost:22259/session/5627381E-0A38-4DE4-BF2C-71FC625049F6/source 
Waiting for new request... 

Received a request for http://localhost:22259/session/5627381E-0A38-4DE4-BF2C-71FC625049F6/source 
Waiting for new request... 

Received a request for http://localhost:22259/session/5627381E-0A38-4DE4-BF2C-71FC625049F6/cookie 
Waiting for new request... 

Received a request for http://localhost:22259/session/5627381E-0A38-4DE4-BF2C-71FC625049F6 
Waiting for new request... 

Received a request for http://localhost:22259/shutdown 
Stopping server.
```

My Test file is:

```
class SearchTest extends GebReportingSpec{
    def "Searching iPhone 6"(){
        given:
        to EbayHomePage

        when:
        waitFor {at(EbayHomePage)}
        at(EbayHomePage).with {
            headerW.searchField.value("iPhone 6")
            headerW.selectCategory.setSelected("Mobile Phones")
            headerW.searchButton.click()
        }
        waitFor 10, {at(SearchResultPage).itemTitle.isDisplayed()}
        String itemName = at(SearchResultPage).itemTitle.text()
        at(SearchResultPage).itemTitle.click()

        then:
        assert at(ItemDetailsPage).itemName.text()==itemName
    }
}
```

My GebConfig.groovy is:

```
driver = {  System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","D:\\Project\\gebbrowserautomation\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
    driver = { new EdgeDriver() }
}
baseUrl = "https://www.ebay.in"
reportsDir = "build/reports/GebReports"
```

EBayHomePage.groovy is:

```
class EbayHomePage extends Page{
    static url = "/"
    static at = { title == "Electronics, Cars, Fashion, Collectibles, Coupons and More | eBay"}
    static content = {
        headerW {module(HeaderModule)}
        profileModule {module(ProfileModule)}
    }
}
```

HeaderModule.groovy :

```
class HeaderModule extends Module{
    static content = {
        signIn {$("a", text:"Sign in")}
        register {$("a", text:"register")}
        deals {$("a", _sp:"m570.l3188")}
        sell {$("a", _sp:"m570.l1528")}
        help {$("a", _sp:"m570.l1545")}
        trackOrder {$("a", _sp:"m570.l2624")}

        myEbay {$("a", _sp:"m570.l2919")}
        myPaisaPay {$("a.gh-eb-li-a")}

        profileExpand {$("#gh-ug")}

        searchField {$("#gh-ac")}
        selectCategory {$("#gh-cat").module(Select)}
        searchButton {$("#gh-btn")}
    }
}
```

ProfileModule.groovy :

```
class ProfileModule extends Module{
    static content = {
        username {$("li#gh-un")}
        userId {$("#gh-ui")}
        accountSettings {$("a", _sp:"m570.l3399")}
        signout {$("#gh-uo")}
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue? I am not sure but it looks like MicrosoftEdgeDriver issue.

Comment: Error is clear ; `Element info: {Using=xpath, value=/*}`

Comment: @DebanjanB: I didn't used xpath anywhere in my page objects.

Comment: Both `SearchResultPage` and `ItemDetailsPage` are used in your test, but you did not post the classes here. Please update the question in order to provide a fully self-consistent [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).